# Regex matching in python

Tags: regex

This is my string, `EE(P1)BAEEEEEE(P1)(P2)EEAACIIII(P1)(P1)BACIA(P1)AIE`. 
I want to match `)BAEEEEEE(` but not `)(` so basically `(\).*?\() AND NOT (\)\()`
Update: I cannot replace * with + because that will match `)(P2)EEAACIIII(` I don't want that to happen. The only thing I want to match is if something exists between ) and (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `*`, because + means one or more chars (which inturn expects atleast one char) whereas `*` means zero or more.

```
\).+?\(
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "EE(P1)BAEEEEEE(P1)(P2)EEAACIIII(P1)(P1)BACIA(P1)AIE"
>>> re.findall(r'\).+?\(', s)
[')BAEEEEEE(', ')(P2)EEAACIIII(', ')(P1)BACIA(']
>>> re.search(r'\).+?\(', s).group()
')BAEEEEEE('
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to match the string which has `(`, `)` chars in the middle, you may alter the above regex like below.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\)[^()]+\(', s)
[')BAEEEEEE(', ')EEAACIIII(', ')BACIA(']
```

Comment: Yes that would work but then that will match `)(P2)EEAACIIII(` I don't want that to happen

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`\)[^\(]+?\(`

This will match anything between `)` and the first `(` encountered. Hence it will match `)Sgsdgsg(` but not `)(dg)sdgsgsh(` since in `)(dg)sdgsgsh(`, the first `(` is encountered just after `)`, that is in the form `)(`. But it will instead match `)sdgsgsh(`

Comment: If OP don't want to select `)foo)kkf(` then he can use `\)[^\(\)]+?\(`.